# syncing local site database to live site database

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a local site which has a POS for woocommerce, how can i sync the database table of woocommerce orders and products to my live website so that the products that has been add or bought will be less to my live site tables.

Comment: Better question: why is your local site more up to date than your live site?

Comment: Why cant you do POS in your live site from the admin area.

Comment: i put it offline so that there is no delay in our process. even if there is no internet we can process the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway I do not know how your table order and products were setup...

Synching is just very simple. First you will need to loop through the orders and product table based on each product unique identification and in this case an Id to ensure that an existing products or order is not inserted twice.

Finally, You may need to only update a particular item based on date or timestamp that you implement.
For instance if the product timestamp is less than or greater than blablabla...then loop and insert/update.

Thank You.

Comment: i dont have any idea with the sql queries. how can i achieve it sir? just give an example. thanks for response